# Convert a Guid string into BigInteger and vice versa

Tags: c#, guid, biginteger

I can convert a Guid String into a BigInteger using method below. How can I convert BigInteger back to Guid string.

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;

class Class1
{       
    public static BigInteger GuidStringToBigInt(string guidString)
    {
        Guid g = new Guid(guidString);
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(g.ToByteArray());
        return bigInt;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string guid1 = "{90f0fb85-0f80-4466-9b8c-2025949e2079}";

        Console.WriteLine(guid1);
        Console.WriteLine(GuidStringToBigInt(guid1));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check this:

```
public static Guid ToGuid(BigInteger value)
{
     byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
     value.ToByteArray().CopyTo(bytes, 0);
     return new Guid(bytes);
}
```

Edit: [Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9xbrAY)

Comment: This is awesome! I want to accept this answer but Stack Overflow says I have to wait 2 minutes. Lol.

Comment: This isn't correct. Try from one to the other for 64bf6328-de36-48a1-af69-378183c37a00 throws "Byte array for GUID must be exactly 16 bytes long" This whole thing smells.

Comment: Yes. It indeed gave "Byte array for Guid must be exactly 16 bytes long" for the example provided by @Will. Any resolution for that @Simonare?

Comment: Have no definitive proof that this is correct, but it survived a few million repititions. Not that this means anything whatsoever to the vast number of guids out there.

Comment: Yeah! That issue is fixed now. Thanks @Simonare!

Answer (score 1):

If you want positive integer representations the conversion in the question and the reverse conversion in the accepted answer both don't work for all values. For example, converting from `ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff` to a BigInteger will give `-1`. And converting from `340282366920938463463374607431768211455` to a Guid will give an exception.

If you do want the positive representation (useful if you're trying to convert bases, for example) you'll need to add an additional byte with the value zero to the end of your byte array. (See this
[illustration for a positive values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Numerics_BigInteger__ctor_System_Byte___) right before the frist "Remarks" section).

```
public static BigInteger GuidStringToBigIntPositive(string guidString)
{
    Guid g = new Guid(guidString);
    var guidBytes = g.ToByteArray();
    // Pad extra 0x00 byte so value is handled as positive integer
    var positiveGuidBytes = new byte[guidBytes.Length + 1];
    Array.Copy(guidBytes, positiveGuidBytes, guidBytes.Length);

    BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(positiveGuidBytes);
    return bigInt;
}

public static string BigIntToGuidStringPositive(BigInteger bigint)
{
    // Allocate extra byte to store the large positive integer
    byte[] positiveBytes = new byte[17];
    bigint.ToByteArray().CopyTo(positiveBytes, 0);
    // Strip the extra byte so Guid can handle it
    byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
    Array.Copy(positiveBytes, bytes, bytes.Length);
    return new Guid(bytes).ToString();
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Y8J0L) demonstrating both methods.